# Python: Parse web content for lines containing a specific character and store into a file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am new to python. I have this webpage containing the contents:

```
<Response>
<Value type="ABC">107544</Value>
<Value type="EFG">10544</Value>
<Value type="ABC">77544</Value>
```

I would like to parse lines containing ABC and store only the numbers within a temporary text file. How can I do this?

Currently I have

```
htmlpage = urllib2.urlopen(<URL>)
result = htmlpage.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your result into `BeautifulSoup`, and you will be able to extract any data very easily without regex

## UPDATED:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = '''<div class="test">
             <a href="example">Result 1</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="test">
             <a href="example2">Result 2</a>
            </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(result)

for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'test'}):
    print div.find('a').text

Result 1
Result 2
```

Comment: So I got to the point where I get only [<value type="OS">1083-477544</value>] using Beautiful soup. How do I parse it to get only the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I'll second the suggestion to use BeutifulSoup for parsing HTML, but if you insist on using regex, you can try something like:

```
re.findall('(?<=type="ABC">).+?(?=<\/)', text, re.S)
```

Comment: How would I do it in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: So I used Beautiful Soup and was able to get

<value type="ABC">
    10-399575
   </value>
   <value type="DEF">
    8-399415
   </value>

How can I get only the text after ABC?

Answer (score 1):

Or lxml and xpaths

```
>>>from lxml import html

>>>result = html.fromstring('''<Response>
<Value type="ABC">107544</Value>
<Value type="EFG">10544</Value>
<Value type="ABC">77544</Value></Response>''')

>>>result.xpath('//value[@type="ABC"]/text()')
...['107544', '77544']
```